# Should the first word after a dash used as self-interruption be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, speech, dashes

When writing dialogue, a dash can be used to denote interruption.  For example:

> “Hello, can I ask you about—”
>
> “No.”

If a character is interrupting themself, should the first word of the interruption be capitalized?  In other words, should the word *oh* be capitalized in the following quote?

> “Have you seen — oh my God, you’re him!”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jane Straus](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/dashes.asp) advocates lower-case to follow a dash even after a sentence fragment:

> I wish you would—oh, never mind.

To adapt her comments, This shows an abrupt change in thought and warrants an em dash.

Usage on the internet is non-uniform.

Comment: She doesn't clearly state a rule, so much as implies common usage to semicolons or other compound sentence constructs.

Comment: And "usage on the internet is non-uniform" is so obvious it may be a tautology.

Comment: @DougM If I see someone smoking, I feel I'm justified in considering him a smoker; I quoted Straus's example verbatim. If she had labelled this practice a rule, I probably would have looked a lot further to find someone of equal stature saying or clearly implying it wasn't – I just pointed out that it's not universal practice.

Comment: I suggest if there's a problem there, that's using a dash rather than ellipsis… 

The past is another country and today, doesn't "I wish you would — oh, never mind" read more like an attempt at recording sound that speech?

To me if we put grammar or semantics before phonetics, it would be more like: "I wish you would… Oh, never mind."

Comment: I'd agree with Truss that the dash is a more abrupt signal than an ellipsis. The ellipsis is still, after all, used to show a trailing off of a thought, train of speech (among other things, but this must at least inform). In fact Truss says as much: 'Experienced writers know that these marks are not interchangeable. Note how dashes subtly change the tone of the following sentences ...' (she adds the example I give, after the 'ellipsised' alternative).

Answer (score 0):

It would be “I wish you would….  Oh, never mind.”
“…” Is a pause but you still need a period after if you’re ending the sentence.

Comment: The question was asking about capitalization after a _dash_ not an ellipsis.